# How do I call a route with Javascript and destroy data from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 and I need to destroy data from database, I've the following code

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deletePub" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title" id="modalPublicationTitle">Confirm Publication Delete</h6>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">    
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">Really, do you want to delete this publication?</div>
                    <a href="#" id="btn-confirmDeletePub" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Yes, Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn-confirmDeletePub").click(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var publicationId = window.location.href.split("/")[4]

    console.log(publicationId);

    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "/publications/" + publicationId,
        data: JSON.stringify(publicationId),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
    });

  });

});
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('publications','PublicationController);
```

PublicationController.php

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $publication = Publication::find($id);
    $publication->users()->detach($publication->id);
    $publication->topics()->detach($publication->id);
    $publication->authors()->detach($publication->id);

    $publication->details()->delete();

    //$publication->delete();

    Redirect('/users')->with('success', 'Publication deleted correctly.');

}
```

All the following code should call the `btn-confirmDeletePub` function of the JS file when I click on the `Yes, delete` button. The JS button captures the id of the publication to be deleted and will sent to the `destroy($id)` function of the `PublicationController`, but for some reason this function it's not called, the error is inside the JS and I'm sure, but I do not know how to solve.

In Google Chrome's Console I get the following error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:8000/publications 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: The error points to a problem with your php code. Also, you're sending a `DELETE` request. I'd stick to GET and POST, since it's possible that laravel doesn't handle DELETE requests in the first place. Maybe this causes the 500 error. `JSON.stringify(publicationId)` is useless unless publicationID is an object or array. `dataType: "json"` means you expect JSON, but your controller isn't sending back JSON, or is it? Not sure.

Comment: is js code in another js file that you include in the page or its written under the page?

Comment: @ChrisG Laravel [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) specifically use the DELETE verb for the `destroy` method.

Comment: @ChrisG you're right about the JSON, but Laravel specific to use DELETE for 'destroy' method, as sam said.

Comment: @SalarBahador yeah, I'm using an external JS file and I've correctly imported it, cause I saw on the console the publicationId of the publication.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that laravel not only supports DELETE but encourages using it. Anyway, just wanted to note that it's not at all paradoxical to use POST instead, since how you handle the method and parameters in laravel is completely up to you. In my APIs I usually use GET for almost everything and supply for instance an action and id parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use delete method you must add the method field to ajax call and set the type to post.
as jQuery docs say about the type option: "Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used, but they are not supported by all browsers.

However, if you really want to do that, Symfony should handle this for any request, think of it as a form:

when you send a delete request from a form you should set the method attribute to post and add `{{method_field('DELETE')}}` in the form. in ajax you must do it like that except you pass the method field as data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: route,
    type: 'post',
    data: {_method: 'delete'},
    success: function....
```

In detail:

when you send a delete request from a form your form should look like this:

```
<form action="route" method="post">
{{csrf_filed()}}
{{method_filed('DELETE')}}

</form>
```

when you press a submit button laravel looks form input with the name of "_method" and matches the request with route method and URL.

So if you want to send a request through ajax you must do it the way you are doing right now, except you must add the method field in data that you send with ajax.

Comment: It's paradoxical, how can I use a "POST" method, if I need to use the "DELETE"? What do you mean about? Could you be more clear with your solution please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Zoythrus I edited my answer. but I rewrite it here.  think of it as a form, when you send a delete request from a from you should set the method attribute to post and add {{method_field('DELETE')}} in the form. in ajax you must do it like that except you pass the method field as data.

Comment: The choice to not use a form is desired, and I couldn't use it because the button isn't submit but an <a href> by choice and I cannot do otherwise.

Comment: The route publications/{publication} with DELETE method already exist and I wanna use it, I wont declare another function method to solve my purpose.

Comment: I will try your solution and I will let you know.

Comment: @Zoythrus look my friend, I said think of it as a form. its not a form its actually an ajax call. all you have to do is just add _method: delete to your ajax call. nothing is special here

Comment: @Zoythrus ok, I'll be here

Comment: @Zoythrus any luck?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169968/discussion-between-zoythrus-and-salar-bahador).